# GUI Text Editor for ARM Linux? Kinda like Sublime if possible,with syntax highlighting for at least Python,Lua and C/C++

Tags: linux, text-editor, sublime-text

For coding in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my ODROID C2. I'm aware of nice online tools, but an offline editor will help me more. Please don't answer Vim or Emacs(I'm already looking on ‘em). I'm so heartbreak to not be able to use Sublime haha

Comment: There are tons of editors which would match your description. Could you please be a bit more specific? What features do you need? Examples include, but are not limited to: syntax highlighting (what programming languages?), code folding, tabs for multiple files – or rather being lightweight and plain. Like the RasPis, I guess your little friend runs on some Debian derivate, so the repos are open for you.

Comment: Looks like vscode can work. I'll make an answer if I test it. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BuildingVisualStudioCodeOnARaspberryPi3.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think that every Sublime user owes it to themselves to check out Atom (atom.io), but it looks like you'll need to get it working yourself: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/7822.

Personally, I've always liked Geany (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/arm64/geany). It's light weight, has syntax highlighting, and some nice features. I've always had good luck with it on resource-constrained Ubuntu boxes, but I've never tried on an ARM platform.

Answer (score 1):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/features) should be available for your distribution in the standard repositories or [here](https://launchpad.net/~damien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable).

- Excellent Cross Platform IDE
- Works with multiple Compilers & Debuggers for C/C++/Fortran
- Syntax Highlighting for lots of languages
- Spell Check inside comments & strings
- Code Folding
- Code Completion
- Smart Indent
- [Plug-ins](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Code::Blocks_Plugins)
- If not available for your distro then you can download and build the source code from the release tar.gz or from svn.
- Also available for Windows and *slightly dated* OS-X.

[image]

If not then my suggestion would be to use a python or java based editor that uses any of the GTK, GHK+, wxPython or QT/pySide/PyQt*X* based GUI tool kits. *For the wx based ones you will may have to build the wxPython tool chain for your target and for the QT based you will have to locate a build of QT that is compatible with your target.*

There is a nice list [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors) aimed at python development but many have syntax highlighting, and more, for many languages.

To give you some highlights of Java based IDEs:

### [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/)

- Java Based
- Support for Java, JavaScript, JSP, C/C++, PHP, XML, HTML, Groovy out of the box
- more languages from [plug-in](http://plugins.netbeans.org/) components, *there is even a Sublime theme*.

### [PyCharm](http://jetbrains.com/pycharm/)

- Commercial or Free
- Java Based
- Understands and supports TextMate bundles for additional languages.

Answer (score 1):

Is Geany in your repos? It shows up for me in raspbian (wheezy), and it is what I use for (some) Java, PHP, HTML/javascript/css, etc.  Actually configurable to run/build your code, so it is really a super light weight IDE.  But it works great as just a text editor if that is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) supports Linux on ARM and AArch64. It's like light weight Sublime analog. Supports syntax highlighting of course.